# Is it possible to load properties from a web service during spring boot application startup?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, external

I am building a new spring boot application deployable to bluemix (cloud foundry) which needs to do the following:

1. use spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector to discover user-provided "properties service": read the service URL and credentials from VCAP_APPLICATION env variable.
   This step is completed.
2. connect to properties service via HTTP call, receive JSON response, parse individual property values and expose them as application properties (in Environment object?)

What would be the correct solution for this in spring-boot app?

In older non-boot Spring app, the property service call would be initiated early in Spring lifecycle by a class that extended PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer and the property collection from the service would be handled inside postProcessBeanFactory() method call of the same class.

```
public class CustomPopertiesFactory 
    extends PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
    implements EnvironmentAware {

private Properties properties;

getServiceCredentials() {
   // parse VCAP_APPLICATION json
   final String localVcapServices = System.getProperty("VCAP_SERVICES");
  // extract url, username, pwd to connect to the service
}

connectToService () {
   // via HTTP request using RestTemplate
   // parse JSON response and add properties to this.properties
    ... this.properties.put("prop1", valueFromJson);

}


@Override
public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {

    getServiceCredentials();

    connectToService();

    // load values from properties service into app properties
    setProperties(properties);
    // continue with lifecycle and load properties from other sources
    super.postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory);
}
```

}

That was painful to maintain and switch between cloud and local spring profiles IMO and I am wondering if spring boot has a better way of handling external properties.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up replacing "properties service" with [spring-cloud-config-server](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html)
and using [spring-cloud-config-client](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_client.html)
in my spring boot application to consume properties from spring-cloud-config-server.